# [2.83]Missing Weight Options

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

In weight paint mode[2.79], there was an option that could assign many vertices at once with a specific weight. You could also remove any weight on any vertex with another option right beside it. You could also select or deselect any vertices on a vertex group.

How do I enable this feature, is there a hot key, or a specific mode to go to for it to show up? A button somewhere?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After watching a few videos, apparently this one button 'Vertex Selection', which is only seen by accessing 'Weight Paint' mode, enables this useful feature.

EDIT: You have to have weight data on any vertex on any object on the scene, for the column to become available.
[image]

Comment: It is also visible in edit mode, it is hidden in object mode because in object mode you cannot select vertices, so there is no need to have those options visible